# Web Application Hosting on my own server

Tags: jakarta-ee, hosting, jboss7.x

I really need your help concerning Hosting a JEE web application ( MySQL database hosted on another server, EJBs, JPA, Servlets, JSP , JBOSS server)

I want to host it for free just to test access ( no need to be a final solution but just to deliver it for test hen I will look for a long time solution)

Please I'm in rush with that could you help me

thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://www.openshift.com/ .
You can try it out for free, deploy your application server, even database if you need it.
You'll also get free subdomain so you can test your application.